# Finding the last character before a given character inside a Java String

Tags: java, string

Say I have the following string:

```
String string = "122045b5423";
```

In Java, what would be the most efficient way in finding the last 2 before the b?
I know I can split the string and then use lastIndexOf() method from String class, but 
is there a more efficient way with less creating of variables. Can there be a method in the StringBuilder class that will allow us to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest (with almost zero memory-overhead) is to simply scan the string yourself:

```java
int findLastCharBeforeChar(final String string, final char anchor, final char needle) {
  int i = string.length() - 1;
  while (i >= 0 && string.charAt(i) != anchor) {
    --i;
  }
  while (i >= 0) {
    if (string.charAt(i) == needle) return i;
    --i;
  }
  return i;
}
```

If you want to make that a bit shorter (but likely minimally slower and definitely harder to read):

```java
int findLastCharBeforeChar(final String string, final char anchor, final char needle) {
  char target = anchor;
  while (i >= 0) {
    final char ch = string.charAt(i);
    if (ch == target) target = needle;
    if (target == needle && ch == target) return i;
    --i;
  }
  return i;
}
```

---

Not what was asked (most efficient), but followed up in the comments for the "shortest" solution, there you go (note that this is far from efficient, and depending on where you call it, this could be bad):

```java
string.split('b')[0].lastIndexOf('2');
```

You didn't specify in your OP what should happen if `'b'` is not part of the input string. Should the result be `-1`? (will be with my first implementation) or should the method then just return the index of the last `'2'` in the string (the string split solution)? Changing the method to handle this case as well is trivial, just check if the first loop terminated at `-1` and reset the index to the string's last index.

But this is somewhat moot. You put the 9 lines of code in a method, write proper unit tests for it and then call your new method. Calling the new method is: a) a one-liner b) efficient c) likely to be inlined by the JVM

Comment: haha I was expecting a one line code. I guess I will use lastIndexOf and split the String. @knittl

Comment: You asked for the "most efficient" way. Splitting a string is far from most efficient. (It needs to allocate memory for 2 news strings and 1 array to hold them.)

Comment: That's true. I meant to say the way with less code. @knittl So not even the new Java with Lambdas can make this type of problem less wordy?

Comment: @knittl Oops. That'll teach me to get on SO before I've woken up properly. Thanks for catching it.

Comment: Thanks for the nice one liner. @knittl I can use that and handle any returns of -1

Comment: Yes I should have thought about writing all those little methods on my project. Problem is I'm a math major not a computer science major. I will just finish the project the long difficult way. From a software development point of view, writing that method and re-using it makes more sense. Can you explain how would you write a unit test. Will the purpose be to catch if and when the index = -1? @knittl

Comment: The purpose of the unit test is to define and document valid inputs and outputs for a function, the same way a mathematical function is expected to behave (same input = same output). In your example, your tests can document the expected behavior for: `b` and `2` are the same character (what happens if you search for the last `b` before `b`? Which index should your method return?). What happens if the "anchor" character is not found? What happens if one comes before the other? What happens if the string is empty? What happens if the string is null? What happens when one character is not found?

Comment: I want to follow up on the comment of "I'm a math major, not a CS major, so I want to do it the long difficult way" – that's no excuse since you already know the proper, and easy, solution to your problem. It would be the same me saying "I'm a CS major, not a math major, so I won't follow math notation" … I'll just write "1 + 1 = 2 + 4 = 6 * 7 = 42 / 3 = 14". Sure, it works, but it makes everybody's life more difficult. Or not sharpening knifes when cooking, "because I'm not a chef, I'll use just dull knives". … why complicate matters when the short, easy way does exactly what you want?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a more compact solution, how about regex?

```
// A 2, followed by arbitrary chars that are not a 2 and finally a b
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(2)[^2]*b");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.print("Start index: " + matcher.start());
    System.out.print(" End index: " + matcher.end());
    System.out.println(" Found: " + matcher.group());
}
```

Have not tested it, but something similar should work

Answer (score 0):

Look at the method [substring](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) of String class (or [subSequence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#subSequence-int-int-)). That should give you what you need.

the code Should be something like this

```
String result = null;
int index = myString.indexOf("b");
if(index > -1) {
  if(index >= 2) {
    result = myString.substring(index - 2, index);
  } else {
    result = myString.substring(0, index);
  }
}
```